# Non admin user is not able to edit the List in salesforce

Tags: list-view

I've  two User with same profile & different permission set to them.

My requirement is, both user can able to edit the list view on object.

But, In actual only one user out of them is able to edit the list view and other user is not able to edit the list view.

What it the wrong here. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the profile and permission set, if create and customize list views permission has been provided.

Navigate to the appropriate profile belonging to users who should  have this permission (Setup > Manage Users > Profiles) and select the profile that you would like to update. Select System Permissions. Select Edit and check the Create and Customize List Views checkbox. Save the Profile.